# Is there a Perl module to test internet connection speed?

Tags: perl, connection, performance

Does anybody know a module to test the speed of internet-connection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Speed as in bandwidth? Or as in latency? For the latter, just use [Net::Ping](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Ping).

For bandwidth, I don't know if there's anything ready made, there's 2 approaches:

1. You can try to leverage [ibmonitor](http://ibmonitor.sourceforge.net/about.html)
2. Otherwise, to measure download bandwidth find a web site that lets you measure bandwidth by downloading a large file (or find such a large file on high-performance site); start the timer, start downloading that file (e.g. using [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl) or any other module you wish - or [Net::FTP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libnet) if your file is on FTP site) - measure how long it takes and divide by the file size.

   Similar logic for measuring upload bandwidth, but instead of finding large file, you need to find a place on the internet (like a public repository) that'd allow uploading one.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings; use strict;
use 5.010;
use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday tv_interval);
use LWP::Simple;
use File::stat;

my %h = (
    '500x500'   => 505544,
    '750x750'   => 1118012,
    '1000x1000' => 1986284,
    '1500x1500' => 4468241,
    '2000x2000' => 7907740,
);

my $pixel = '1000x1000';
my $url_file = 'http://speedserver/file'.$pixel.'.jpg';
my $file = 'file'.$pixel.'.jpg';

unlink $file or die $! if -e $file;
my $start = gettimeofday;
my $response = getstore( $url_file, $file );
my $end = gettimeofday;

open my $fh, '>>', 'speed_test.txt' or die $!;
    say $fh scalar localtime;
    if ( not is_success $response ) {
        say $fh "error occured:";
        say $fh "HTTP response code = $response";
    }
    else {
        my $size = stat( $file )->size if -e $file;
        $size ||= 0;
        if ( $size == $h{$pixel} ) {
            my $bit = $size * 8;
            my $time = $end - $start;
            my $kbps = int( ( $bit / $time ) / 1000 );
            say $fh "$kbps kbit/s";
            say $fh "$pixel : $size";
        }
        else {
            say $fh "error occured:";
            say $fh "file_size is $size - file_size expected $h{$pixel}";
        }   
    }
    say $fh "";
close $fh;
```

Comment: `$ten` is a poor name for that variable.

Comment: It's not easy - when I try to find good variable-names they mostly grow to much in length.

Comment: It's really easy. That's not really $ten, it's $file_size, or something similar. Think about what it represents, not what it is.